# Re-using existing ansible group_vars with molecule

Tags: molecule

I am working on adding tests to all my existing Ansible roles using Molecule. 
My existing Ansible playbooks utilize levels of variables like such:

```
file: playbook_dir/group_vars/all
contents: global variables, applicable to all everything (hosts, inventories etc.)

file: playbook_dir/inventories/<inventory>/group_vars/all
contents: variables applicable to all hosts in this inventory.

file: playbook_dir/inventories/<inventory>/group_vars/<group>
contents: variables applicable only to this group.
```

When setting up Molecule for my existing roles, I need access to at the very least the 'global variables' (first in my list), I managed to achieve this by adding links, like such:

```
provisioner:
  name: ansible
  inventory:
    links:
      group_vars: ../../../../group_vars # These are the 'global' group_vars as described above.
```

So far so good, right. However, there are several roles that require variables to be set which are not part of the 'global' group_vars; i.e. inventory specific ones. 
I've found that:

1. The links only allow a single link to be made, so linking to multiple group_vars does not seem to be an option.
2. inventory.links.group_vars and inventory.group_vars are mutual exclusive.

My question: How can I re-use my existing 'global variables', but also either a) use existing inventory specific group_vars, or b) define inventory specific group_vars?

Answer (score 0):

You can define inventory `group_vars` specific to you molecule test(s) directly in `molecule.yml`. This also works for `host_vars`

Ref: https://molecule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/configuration.html#id22 (search for 'inventory:' on the page).

Comment: Yes, but when you do that, you cannot link to an existing vars file anymore. My question is whether there is a way to do both.